# TFS build agent 2012 - actual msbuild command

Tags: msbuild

I have a situation where I for debugging purposes would like to "build like my build agent, but locally on my developer machine" - and for this to work I need to know the exact msbuild command that is executed on my build agent.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find this from either of the logs available from the build view.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried changing the verbosity of the build to diagnostic and then looking through the build summary/logs?

Answer (score 0):

Changed diagnostics to "Normal" and there it was.